# Output string formatting in python

Tags: python, string, formatting

I am encountering an error in outputting a formatted string. I am using Python2.6

```
lat = 23.456
long = 34.129
# I want to output lat and long, both occupying 8 columns in width, right justified and with 2 values beyond the decimal point
site_file = open('test.site','w')
site_file.write('[{:8.2f}{:8.2f}]'.format(lat,long))
```

I get the following error:
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: ```long``` is a buit-in function for converting to a long integer.  Please don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: The code you posted works for me - v2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2.6 and earlier require that you specify the index of the formatted values. Here is an example:

```
'[{} {}]'.format(a, b)    # Python 2.7 and later 
'[{0} {1}]'.format(a, b)  # Python 2.6 and earlier
```

I do not have a Python 2.6 interpreter handy, but I believe this is the syntax that you need:

```
site_file.write('[{0:8.2f}{1:8.2f}]'.format(lat,long))
```

Comment: From the docs for 2.6 ```Each replacement field contains either the numeric index of a positional argument, or the name of a keyword argument.```